# Ubuntu 16.04 issues with scaling menu bars and changing resolution

Tags: 16.04, display, dell, display-resolution

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu on my dell xps 9350 13". It has a 4k display which makes everything on the screen appear very small. With my last install I fixed this just by scaling up the menu and title bars up to 2 in display settings. Or by dropping my resolution. However right now neither of those options are working for me. I can change the value in the menu bar scaling but it does not actually update the display and when I go to change the screen resolution the only option it gives me is 3800 x 1800.

Any assistance would be very helpful
Thanks.